# Constructor being called twice

Tags: c#, ios, .net

I have a .Net for iOS application using .Net 7.

Short history: the app was Xamarin and runs on Mac and iOS. I moved it to **.Net for iOS** and **.Net for Mac**, as that was the easiest transition. MAUI is not fully baked yet, and would have been a big change. The issue below is only in the iOS version, NOT the Mac version, although the code is shared. This issue did not occur in Xamarin.iOS.

In the app, I have pages that I display containing shapes and text boxes on a canvas (UIView subclass). The textboxes are a subclass of UITextView called RichTextView.

My RichTextView contains constructors:

```
        public RichTextView(NativeHandle handle) : base(handle)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public RichTextView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public RichTextView() : base()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public RichTextView(CoreGraphics.CGRect frame) : base(frame)
        {
            Initialize();
        }
```

The `Initialize` function configures the RichTextView delegates, KeyCommands etc.

In the canvas view (ObjectCanvas, subclass of UIView), I have a function to create these RichTextViews as required:

```
        private RichTextView CreateNewTextViewAt(Rect rect, string newId = null)
        {
            var newTextView = new RichTextView();
            ...
```

And then sets up constraints, borders, GestureRecognizers etc.

All good so far.

However... in the function that loads all objects (shapes, textboxes etc), something weird happens (note: the tb object is a textbox descriptor):

```
                   //  Create the textbox with the right size/location and id.
                    richtv = CreateNewTextViewAt(tb.frame, tb.id);

                    //  Is this an autosized text box, or a manually sized one.
                    if (!tb.autosize)
                        richtv.ChangeWidthTo(tb.frame.width);

                    // create the attributed string to put into it.
                    var nsas = AppleStyles.MDToNSAS(tb.text, tb.attachments);
                    richtv.TextStorage.SetString(nsas);

                    //  Set the cursor. (make sure its got a valid value by clamping)
                    richtv.SelectedRange = new NSRange(tb.cursor, 0).ClampRange(richtv.TextStorage.Length);
```

That last line is where the problem appears - because for some reason when it is executed, the `RichTextView(NativeHandle)` constructor is called, with the handle having the address of the `richtv` object that has already been created, and `this` having the same value. This causes all settings in the RichTextView to be reset.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening? Is this normal for the new NativeHandle constructor? (C# says constructors are never called twice).

[One hack could be to try and make the NativeHandle constructor a no-op. yuck! I'd rather understand what's going on].

Thank you.

[EDIT - some extra detail below from the debugger]

When I turn on the debugger option to Step Into External Code - I get the following stack trace. You can see the Constructor being invoked from within SelectedRange:

```
AppleLibrary.RichTextView..ctor(ObjCRuntime.NativeHandle handle) in AppleLibrary/RichTextView.cs:1592
System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke() in 
System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.InterpretedInvoke(object obj, System.Span<object> args, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) in 
System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.InlinedInvoke(object obj, System.Span<object> args, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) in 
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject<Foundation.NSObject>(System.IntPtr ptr, System.RuntimeType type, ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) in 
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(System.IntPtr ptr, System.RuntimeType target_type, ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution, bool evenInFinalizerQueue, bool createNewInstanceIfWrongType, bool created) in 
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWithType(System.IntPtr ptr, System.IntPtr type_ptr, bool created) in 
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.get_nsobject_with_type(System.IntPtr obj, System.IntPtr type, bool created, System.IntPtr exception_gchandle) in 
ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_NSRange() in 
UIKit.UITextView.set_SelectedRange(Foundation.NSRange value) in 
AppleLibrary.ObjectCanvas.Load(CoreLibrary.Note note, CoreLibrary.Edit edit) in AppleLibrary/ObjectCanvas.cs:801
```

It seems to go "set_SelectedRange -> GetNSObjectWithType -> MissingCtorResolution -> Constructor".

That is a little weird, perhaps I'm missing a constructor? Or perhaps the RichTextView wasn't properly constructed?

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger and see what is happening. Unclear why you think the constructor is being run twice, you would have to show a [mcve] with the issue

Comment: Stepping through the code using the debugger is how I found the cause of the crash. When that line "richtv.SelectedRange = ..." is executed, the next thing that happens is the constructor is run (I can step through the properties being initialised, then the RichTextView(NativeHandler) being executed, with the handler, and this pointing to the object that was already created.

Comment: @Charlieface - There's a little more detail from turning on "step into external code" in the debugger. You can see the constructor being invoked from inside SelectedRange! I've edited the original text above to include that trace.

Comment: I can't find the exact documentation for the `RichTextView(NativeHandle handle)` constructor form, but I did find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/objcruntime.class.-ctor?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#objcruntime-class-ctor(system-intptr)). It seems that that constructor receives an unmanaged native object instance and is to return a managed instance.  I suspect that you should either not implement this initialiser (if this is an option) or simply call the base class implementation.  Do not call your `initialise` method in this constructor.

Comment: "This causes all settings in the RichTextView to be reset." seems like you actually have two different `RichTextView` objects here, but might be wrong

Comment: This also seems relevant - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14046 - The constructor you have is equivalent to the constructor I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @Paulw11 - removing the NativeHandle constructor (just commenting it out) causes the following exception: "Unable to marshal the parameter #1 whose managed type is 'Foundation.NSNotification' to managed.". So I suspect that this constructor is required to (as you say) convert a native object to a managed object. I had seen that article on GitHub, which was a little disturbing (no warnings, no hints) - but the article didn't really clue me in on the meaning.

Comment: I am not fluent in C#, but can you just replace the call to `Initialize()` with a call to `super(handle)` or `base(handle)` or whatever the C# syntax is?

Comment: @Paulw11 - (cont) Putting the constructor back but removing the "initialise" method does work BUT all the property initialisers still run and reset their values. So moving all property initialisers to the Initialize function, and everything works. This is most weird though... None of my other UI sub-classes have this problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 - base(handle) is what is there now.

Comment: Bottom line - I can make this work by removing all automatic property initializers (moving them to the Initialize function), and by removing Initialize from the NativeHandle constructor.  I don't know why it fails before... and don't know why the same code works fine on .Net for Mac (the RichTextView class is shared).

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry, I don't know what a "managed" instance is vs unmanaged, so I can't offer any insights into what is happening.  Maybe someone with more C#/Xamarin knowledge can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is quite an "answer" as such... more of the workaround, plus some unanswered questions.

In .Net for iOS, you can have native classes and managed classes. And it is possible to turn a native into a managed class using GetNSObject. This also happens automatically - when .Net requires a managed object, it will call the `Class(NativeHandler)` constructor on the existing object. Note that your constructor for NativeHandler *probably* should just call base(handle).

This means that it is possible for a constructor to be called twice if you are creating UIView subclasses yourself - once by you to create and configure it, and once by .Net to convert to a managed object.

The issue appears to be that all automatic property initialisers get called a second time when the second constructor is called, which means that many of your properties will be reset. And worst of all... you can't control when that second constructor will be called.

So *if* you suffer from this problem, there are a set of things you will need to do to work around it:

- have a default IntPtr (or NativeHandler) constructor that simply calls base(handle).
- have an initialisation function that is *not* called by the above constructor, but is called by the other constructors.
- Remove all automatic property initialisers and put them in the initialisation function.

While C# says constructors are only called once - .Net for iOS calls them twice sometimes - once for a "normal" constructor, and again to convert to a managed object.

If someone knows a better way to handle this, or can tell me why this only affects *some* objects, let me know.

Comment: You may to open an issue on the appropriate GitHub asking about the  automatic property initialisation. Given that the managed object constructor is providing an existing native object it would see to be a bug for that constructor in the base class to reinitialise automatic properties

Comment: Grrr. this one gets even worse. The NativeHandle constructor is called repeatedly, and continually resets all local properties of the object (even when they don't have auto property initialisers).  Documentation says that the NativeHandle constructor should be called once and the wrapped object retained.

Comment: And dammit! I can't report this because the .Net issue reporting system simply returns "Sorry, we couldn't send your report, because the server connection timed out. Please retry now or sign out from Visual Studio, sign in using Visual Studio and try again. " This is both through visual studio and through the web page. Grrrr.

Comment: Took all weekend, but I've been able to isolate the function that causes the problem. Create a small project using a default SPA .Net for iOS project, Create a subclass of UITextView (call it RichTextView). Programmatically add it onto the page in ViewDidLoad. Add a custom delegate (subclass of uITextViewDelegate), and create a DidChangeSelection handler (blank). Now the NativeHandle function gets called and resets all values every time you interact with the RichTextView. Comment out DidChangeSelection, problem goes away. [NOTE: this is all done in the simulator]

Comment: And the problem has been reported to MS.